# java classpath with junit and test class inside a package

Tags: java, junit, classpath

I'm following this [JUnit Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started).

I am able to compile my test class ok:

```
java -cp .:junit-4.12.jar foo/bar/FancyPantsTest.java
```

But I'm having an issue with (I assume) how to properly set the classpath when calling `java`. This command fails:

```
java -cp .:junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore foo/bar/FancyPantsTest
```

Error I get:

```
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [foo/bar/FancyPantsTest]
```

What's the correct way to run this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
java -cp .:junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore foo.bar.FancyPantsTest
```

While slashes were used to refer to the FancyPantsTest source file when compiling, use dots when referring to the FancyPantsTest class file.